# Trying to find In Between

Tags: sql, sql-server

Data Sample

```
ACCOUNT  STATUS  EFF_DT     EXP_DT
1234     C       15Jun2018  31Dec9999
1234     A       14Oct2015  15Jun2018
```

C means they cancelled.
EFF_DT means cancellation date
AND EXP_DT also is also their cancellation date. I'm trying to find out if they cancel between 8 and 14 days after we contact them. Right now I able to see if they cancelled from contact between 1-30.

I have an SQL code where it states `Contact Date + 30`. So the result 30 days after the contact date:

```
AND B.EFF_DT <= (A.CONTACT_DT+30)

AND B.EXP_DT > (A.CONTACT_DT+30)
```

I need assistance in terms of finding an inbetween range. 
So I want to find `Contact_DT` between 8 and 14

So looking for the result between after 8 days of contact and after 14 days of contact.

Comment: Could you provide sample data and expected the result? So we can help easily.

Comment: WHen you say *So looking for the result between after 8 days of contact and after 14 days of contact.* is this based on the exp_dt or eff_dt? BTW, you should really use `DATEADD`

Comment: I provided sample data

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different fields to match with your date In that case try this:

```
    b.eff_dt between dateadd(day,8,a.contact_dt) and dateadd(day,14,a.contact_dt) 
and b.exp_dt between dateadd(day,8,a.contact_dt) and dateadd(day,14,a.contact_dt)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be this?
AND B.EFF_DT <= (BETWEEN A.CONTACT_DT+8 AND A.CONTACT_DT+14)

AND B.EXP_DT > (BETWEEN A.CONTACT_DT+8 AND A.CONTACT_DT+14)

Comment: only correction remove < and > operator.like this :- AND B.EFF_DT  (BETWEEN A.CONTACT_DT+8 AND A.CONTACT_DT+14) AND B.EXP_DT (BETWEEN A.CONTACT_DT+8 AND A.CONTACT_DT+14)

Comment: I'm getting these errors

133        ON A.SUBS_NO = B.SRC_SYS_SUBSCRIBER_NO
134        AND B.EFF_DT (BETWEEN A.CONTACT_DT+8 AND A.CONTACT_DT+14)
                        _         _
                        22        76
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ',', JOIN.  

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample code, and explanation of what it was doing for you, you can change it to 8 days and 14 days appropriately.

```
AND B.EFF_DT <= DATEADD(DAY,8,A.CONTACT_DT)  --not sure if you want 8 or 14 here
AND B.EXP_DT > DATEADD(DAY,14,A.CONTACT_DT)  --not sure if you want 8 or 14 here
```

Alternatively, if your new logic is supposed to be for *both* field you can write that as:

```
AND B.EFF_DT BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,8,A.CONTACT_DT) AND DATEADD(DAY,14,A.CONTACT_DT) 
AND B.EXP_DT BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,8,A.CONTACT_DT) AND DATEADD(DAY,14,A.CONTACT_DT)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dawn685,

Try this. I assume that CONTACT_DT is a date column so adding 8 days or 14 days is made using DATEADD function.
Also, what is happening here is that EFF_DT is either between Contract Date+8 and Contract Date+14 or EXP_DT between Contract Date+8 and Contract Date+14

```
AND 
(
B.EFF_DT BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, 8, A.CONTACT_DT) AND DATEADD(DAY, 14, A.CONTACT_DT) 
OR
B.EXP_DT BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, 8, A.CONTACT_DT) AND DATEADD(DAY, 14, A.CONTACT_DT) 
)
```